# jthread drop-in replacement

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I have a couple of libraries that use jthread, but also are published via vcpkg. The problem I have is that both github and vcpkg's AzureDevOps CI have a version of clang that does not have jthread implemented on MacOS. I was hoping that abeil would have a jthread, but that is not the case.

To reduce the number files that require of `#ifdef __cpp_lib_jthread` I decided to implement a drop in replacement for these cases.

#### jthread.h

```cpp
#ifndef _C9Y_JTHREAD_H_
#define _C9Y_JTHREAD_H_

#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

#include "defines.h"

namespace c9y
{
    #ifdef __cpp_lib_jthread
    using std::jthread;
    using std::stop_token;
    using std::stop_source;
    using std::stop_callback;
    using std::nostopstate;
    #else
    struct StopState;

    struct nostopstate_t {};
    constexpr auto nostopstate = nostopstate_t{};

    class C9Y_EXPORT stop_token
    {
    public:
        stop_token();
        explicit stop_token(std::shared_ptr<StopState> state);
        stop_token(const stop_token& other) noexcept;
        stop_token(stop_token&& other) noexcept;
        ~stop_token();

        stop_token& operator = (const stop_token& other) noexcept;
        stop_token& operator = (stop_token&& other) noexcept;

        [[nodiscard]] bool stop_requested() noexcept;
        [[nodiscard]] bool stop_possible() const noexcept;

        void swap(stop_token& other) noexcept;

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<StopState> state;

    friend class stop_callback;
    };

    inline void swap(stop_token& lhs, stop_token& rhs) noexcept
    {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }

    class C9Y_EXPORT stop_source
    {
    public:
        stop_source();
        explicit stop_source(nostopstate_t nss) noexcept;
        stop_source(const stop_source& other) noexcept;
        stop_source(stop_source&& other) noexcept;
        ~stop_source();

        stop_source& operator = (const stop_source& other) noexcept;
        stop_source& operator = (stop_source&& other) noexcept;

        [[nodiscard]] stop_token get_token() const noexcept;

        bool request_stop() noexcept;
        [[nodiscard]] bool stop_possible() const noexcept;

        void swap(stop_source& other) noexcept;

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<StopState> state;
    };

    inline void swap(stop_source& lhs, stop_source& rhs) noexcept
    {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }

    class C9Y_EXPORT stop_callback
    {
    public:
        template<class C>
        explicit stop_callback(const stop_token& st, C&& cb)
        : token(st), callback(cb)
        {
            self_register();
        }

        template<class C>
        explicit stop_callback(stop_token&& st, C&& cb )
        : token(std::forward<stop_token>(st)), callback(cb)
        {
            self_register();
        }

        ~stop_callback();

    private:
        stop_token             token;
        std::function<void ()> callback;

        void self_register();

        stop_callback(const stop_callback&) = delete;
        stop_callback(stop_callback&&) = delete;
        stop_callback& operator = (const stop_callback& other) noexcept = delete;
        stop_callback& operator = (stop_callback&& other) noexcept = delete;

    friend struct StopState;
    };

    //! Drop in replacement for all cases where std::jthread is not yet implemented.
    //!
    //! @see std::jthread
    class C9Y_EXPORT jthread
    {
    public:
        using id =  std::thread::id;

        jthread() noexcept;
        jthread(jthread&& other) noexcept;

        template<class Function, class... Args>
        requires std::is_invocable_v<std::decay_t<Function>, std::decay_t<Args>...>
        explicit jthread(Function&& f, Args&&... args)
        : impl(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

        template<class Function, class... Args>
        requires std::is_invocable_v<std::decay_t<Function>, stop_token, std::decay_t<Args>...>
        explicit jthread(Function&& f, Args&&... args)
        : impl(std::forward<Function>(f), stop.get_token(), std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

        ~jthread();

        jthread& operator = (jthread&& other) noexcept;

        [[nodiscard]] id get_id() const noexcept;
        [[nodiscard]] bool joinable() const noexcept;

        void join();
        void detach();

        [[nodiscard]] stop_source get_stop_source() noexcept;
        [[nodiscard]] stop_token get_stop_token() noexcept;
        bool request_stop() noexcept;

        void swap(jthread& other) noexcept;

    private:
        stop_source stop = {};
        std::thread impl;

        jthread(const jthread&) = delete;
        jthread& operator = (const jthread& other) noexcept = delete;
    };

    inline void swap(jthread& lhs, jthread& rhs) noexcept
    {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }
    #endif
}

#endif
```

#### jthread.cpp

```cpp
#include "jthread.h"

#ifndef __cpp_lib_jthread
#include <cassert>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

namespace c9y
{
    struct StopState
    {
        std::atomic<bool> request_stop = false;

        // this is not efficient, but it only needs to be correct
        std::mutex callbacks_mutex;
        std::vector<stop_callback*> callbacks;

        void add_callback(stop_callback* callback)
        {
            auto lk = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(callbacks_mutex);
            if (!request_stop)
            {
                callbacks.push_back(callback);
            }
            else
            {
                callback->callback();
            }
        }

        void remove_callback(stop_callback* callback)
        {
            auto lk = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(callbacks_mutex);
            auto i = std::find(begin(callbacks), end(callbacks), callback);
            if (i != end(callbacks))
            {
                callbacks.erase(i);
            }
        }

        void exec_callbacks()
        {
            auto lk = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(callbacks_mutex);
            for (const auto& cb : callbacks)
            {
                assert(cb->callback);
                cb->callback();
            }
            callbacks.clear();
        }
    };

    stop_token::stop_token() = default;

    stop_token::stop_token(std::shared_ptr<StopState> s)
    : state(s) {}

    stop_token::stop_token(const stop_token& other) noexcept = default;
    stop_token::stop_token(stop_token&& other) noexcept = default;
    stop_token::~stop_token() = default;

    stop_token& stop_token::operator = (const stop_token& other) noexcept = default;
    stop_token& stop_token::operator = (stop_token&& other) noexcept = default;

    bool stop_token::stop_requested() noexcept
    {
        if (state)
        {
            return state->request_stop;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool stop_token::stop_possible() const noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>(state);
    }

    void stop_token::swap(stop_token& other) noexcept
    {
        state.swap(other.state);
    }

    stop_source::stop_source()
    : state(std::make_shared<StopState>()) {}

    stop_source::stop_source(nostopstate_t nss) noexcept {}

    stop_source::stop_source(const stop_source& other) noexcept = default;
    stop_source::stop_source(stop_source&& other) noexcept = default;
    stop_source::~stop_source() = default;

    stop_source& stop_source::operator = (const stop_source& other) noexcept = default;
    stop_source& stop_source::operator = (stop_source&& other) noexcept = default;

    stop_token stop_source::get_token() const noexcept
    {
        return stop_token{state};
    }

    bool stop_source::request_stop() noexcept
    {
        if (state && (state->request_stop.exchange(true) == false))
        {
            state->exec_callbacks();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool stop_source::stop_possible() const noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>(state);
    }

    void stop_source::swap(stop_source& other) noexcept
    {
        state.swap(other.state);
    }

    stop_callback::~stop_callback()
    {
        if (token.state)
        {
            token.state->remove_callback(this);
        }
    }

    void stop_callback::self_register()
    {
        if (token.state)
        {
            token.state->add_callback(this);
        }
        else
        {
            callback();
        }
    }

    jthread::jthread() noexcept
    : stop{nostopstate} {}

    jthread::jthread(jthread&& other) noexcept = default;

    jthread::~jthread()
    {
        if (joinable())
        {
            request_stop();
            join();
        }
    }

    jthread& jthread::operator = (jthread&& other) noexcept = default;

    jthread::id jthread::get_id() const noexcept
    {
        return impl.get_id();
    }

    bool jthread::joinable() const noexcept
    {
        return impl.joinable();
    }

    void jthread::join()
    {
        impl.join();
    }

    void jthread::detach()
    {
        impl.detach();
    }

    stop_source jthread::get_stop_source() noexcept
    {
        if (joinable())
        {
            return stop;
        }
        else
        {
            return stop_source{nostopstate};
        }
    }

    stop_token jthread::get_stop_token() noexcept
    {
        return get_stop_source().get_token();
    }

    bool jthread::request_stop() noexcept
    {
        return stop.request_stop();
    }

    void jthread::swap(jthread& other) noexcept
    {
        stop.swap(other.stop);
        impl.swap(other.impl);
    }
}
#endif
```

#### jthread_test.cpp

```cpp
#include <c9y/c9y.h>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(jthread, create_and_destroy)
{
    auto thread = c9y::jthread{};
}

TEST(jthread, launch_thread)
{
    auto tid = c9y::jthread::id{};
    auto thread = c9y::jthread{[&] () {
        tid = std::this_thread::get_id();
    }};

    thread.join();
    EXPECT_NE(tid, std::this_thread::get_id());
}

TEST(jthread, launch_thread_with_args)
{
    auto a = 0u;
    auto thread = c9y::jthread{[&] (unsigned int awnser) {
        a = awnser;
    }, 42u};

    thread.join();
    EXPECT_EQ(a, 42u);
}

TEST(jthread, id)
{
    auto latch = c9y::latch{1};
    auto tid = c9y::jthread::id{};
    auto thread = c9y::jthread{[&] () {
        tid = std::this_thread::get_id();
        latch.count_down();
    }};

    latch.wait();
    EXPECT_EQ(thread.get_id(), tid);
    thread.join();
}

TEST(jthread, empty_id)
{
    auto thread = c9y::jthread{};
    EXPECT_EQ(thread.get_id(), c9y::jthread::id{});
}

TEST(jthread, detach)
{
    auto latch = c9y::latch{1};

    {
        auto thread = c9y::jthread{[&] () {
            latch.wait();
        }};
        thread.detach();
    }

    latch.count_down();
}

TEST(jthread, move_assignment)
{
    auto latch = c9y::latch{1};
    auto outside = c9y::jthread{};
    {
        auto inside = c9y::jthread{[&] () {
            latch.wait();
        }};
        outside = std::move(inside);
        EXPECT_FALSE(inside.joinable());
    }

    EXPECT_TRUE(outside.joinable());
    latch.count_down();
    outside.join();
}

TEST(jthread, move_constructor)
{
    auto latch = c9y::latch{1};

    auto construct = [&] () {
        auto inside = c9y::jthread{[&] () {
            latch.wait();
        }};
        return inside;
    };
    auto outside = construct();

    EXPECT_TRUE(outside.joinable());
    latch.count_down();
    outside.join();
}

TEST(jthread, swap)
{
    auto latch = c9y::latch{1};
    auto a = c9y::jthread{};
    auto b = c9y::jthread{[&] () {
        latch.wait();
    }};

    EXPECT_FALSE(a.joinable());
    EXPECT_TRUE(b.joinable());
    a.swap(b);
    EXPECT_TRUE(a.joinable());
    EXPECT_FALSE(b.joinable());

    latch.count_down();
    a.join();
}

TEST(jthread, request_stop)
{
    auto thread = c9y::jthread{[] (c9y::stop_token token) {
        while (!token.stop_requested())
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }};

    thread.request_stop();
    thread.join();
}

TEST(jthread, automatic_stop_request)
{
    auto thread = c9y::jthread{[] (c9y::stop_token token) {
        while (!token.stop_requested())
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }};
}

TEST(jthread, stop_callback)
{
    auto should_be_called     = std::atomic<unsigned int>{0};
    auto should_not_be_called = std::atomic<unsigned int>{0};

    auto worker = c9y::jthread{[] (c9y::stop_token token) {
        while (!token.stop_requested())
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }};

    auto callback = c9y::stop_callback(worker.get_stop_token(), [&] {
        should_be_called++;
    });

    {
        auto scoped_callback = c9y::stop_callback(worker.get_stop_token(), [&] {
            should_not_be_called++;
        });
    }

    auto stopper_func = [&] {
        worker.request_stop();
    };

    c9y::jthread stopper1(stopper_func);
    c9y::jthread stopper2(stopper_func);
    stopper1.join();
    stopper2.join();

    EXPECT_EQ(1, should_be_called);
    EXPECT_EQ(0, should_not_be_called);

    auto should_be_called_imediatly = std::atomic<unsigned int>{0};
    auto callback2 = c9y::stop_callback(worker.get_stop_token(), [&] {
        should_be_called_imediatly++;
    });

    EXPECT_EQ(1, should_be_called);
    EXPECT_EQ(0, should_not_be_called);
    EXPECT_EQ(1, should_be_called_imediatly);
}

TEST(jthread, called_stop_callback)
{
    auto worker = c9y::jthread{[] (c9y::stop_token token) {
        while (!token.stop_requested())
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }};

    worker.request_stop();

    auto should_be_called_imediatly = std::atomic<unsigned int>{0};
    auto callback2 = c9y::stop_callback(worker.get_stop_token(), [&] {
        should_be_called_imediatly++;
    });

    EXPECT_EQ(1, should_be_called_imediatly);
}

TEST(jthread, expired_stop_callback)
{
    auto worker = c9y::jthread{[] (c9y::stop_token token) {
        while (!token.stop_requested())
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }};

    worker.request_stop();
    worker.join();

    auto should_be_called_imediatly = std::atomic<unsigned int>{0};
    auto callback2 = c9y::stop_callback(worker.get_stop_token(), [&] {
        should_be_called_imediatly++;
    });

    EXPECT_EQ(1, should_be_called_imediatly);
}
```

#### defines.h

You also need this bit of code from `defines.h`:

```cpp
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define C9Y_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define C9Y_EXPORT
#endif
```

The code is targeting C++20; with the obviously missing jthread.

A few notes:

- `stop_source`, `stop_token` and `stop_callback` are passed around by value and thus not accessed through multiple threads. This means that the `shared_ptr` does not need to be synchronized. The underlying reference count is safe, as guaranteed by the standard.
- Any race conditions on `jthread::joinable` are IMHO imagined. I can imagine one in `jthread::get_stop_source`, but then other implementations would also be broken. It seems that I am missing an assumption the standard has on how you can use `jthread::join` and `jthread::get_stop_source`.
- Getting `stop_callback` to work correctly and safely was quite a challenge. I am considering removing it, since I don't need it and the use is quite obscure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like a really good implementation!

## About your notes

> - `stop_source`, `stop_token` and `stop_callback` are passed around by value and thus not accessed through multiple threads. This means that the `shared_ptr` does not need to be synchronized. The underlying reference count is safe, as guaranteed by the standard.

Correct.

> - Any race conditions on `jthread::joinable` are IMHO imagined. I can imagine one in `jthread::get_stop_source`, but then other implementations would also be broken. It seems that I am missing an assumption the standard has on how you can use `jthread::join` and `jthread::get_stop_source`.

`std::jthread::join()` just does exactly what `std::thread::join()` does, nothing more, nothing less. It does not interact with the stop source or token in any way. As far as I can tell, there is no race condition in `std::jthread::joinable()` itself. However, if you call `std::jthread::join()` from one thread and `std::jthread::joinable()` from another, by the time you get the result from `std::jthread::joinable()` the answer might no longer be true. But doing that would be silly anyway. Note that there is a race condition if you call `std::jthread::join()` from multiple threads.

> - Getting `stop_callback` to work correctly and safely was quite a challenge. I am considering removing it, since I don't need it and the use is quite obscure.

It can easily be made to work correctly and safely, but not the most efficient. You tried to add efficiency, and that might interfere with correctness, see below.

## Don't expose more public API than the STL does

The constructor of `c9y::stop_token` that takes a `std::shared_ptr<StopState>` as an argument is `public`, but there is no counterpart in `std::stop_token`. While you don't define `StopState` in `jthread.h`, someone might define it in another source file and then call this constructor with a bogus state. It is easily preventable by making this particular constructor `private`, and adding `stop_source` as a `friend`.

## Define trivial functions in the header file

You have a lot of trivial (copy, move) constructors and destructors. By only declaring them in the header file but defining them in jthread.cpp, code using these classes have to do a function call, which is often more expensive than clearing or copying a few variables if these functions were defined in jthread.hpp instead.

## Don't mix atomics and mutexes

In `StopState` you have both an atomic variable `request_stop` and a mutex. The mutex is there to guard `callbacks`, but it does not cover `request_stop`, likely as intended for performance reasons. The problem now happens in `add_callback()`: the mutex only covers the atomicity of access to the vector `callbacks`, but reading `request_stop` is not part of that! So now you have to wonder if the compiler and/or the CPU are allowed to reorder reads or writes from/to `request_stop` to before/after locking `callbacks_mutex`. If it is, are you still sure your code is correct in all possible ways it can be called from multiple threads simultaneously?

If you are not 100% sure about this, just don't do it, and instead always take the mutex even if you are modifying `request_stop`, which then doesn't need to be made atomic anymore.

Note that mutexes themselves are quite efficient if there is no contention, and it is very likely there will not be any contention: almost all the time it's just one thread that is checking whether it needs to stop.

## Make `StopState` a `class` with `private` member variables

Even if it's only used internally inside jthread.cpp, it's good practice to make `StopState` a proper `class` with `private` member variables, and expose all the logic to modify the state via `public` member functions. That will allow you to catch mistakes more easily, and if you have to refactor `StopState`, you don't have to hunt through the rest of the code to find out where its member variables are being modified. So consider adding two public functions:

- `bool is_stop_requested() const`, which just returns the value of `request_stop`,
- `void stop()`, which sets `request_stop` and runs all the callbacks registered so far.

The member function `exec_callbacks()` should be removed, or perhaps made private and called from `stop()`.

## Naming things

Use verbs for functions, but not for variables. In `StopState`, the variable `request_stop` is confusing, especially since there is a function `request_stop()` in `stop_source`. So it would be better to name it `stop_requested`, although unfortunately there is already the function `stop_requested()` in `stop_token`.

## Fix compiler warnings

There is one warning generated by both GCC and Clang: the parameter `nss` in one of the constructors of `stop_source` is unused. The fixed is to simply remove the name of that parameter.

Comment: The race condition on `joinable` is the following: thread a calls `get_stop_token` to pass to `stop_callback` and the tread is still running and thus gets a valid `stop_token`.  Then thread b calls `request_stop` and calls all callbacks. If the timing works badly the callback does not get called. But the more I think about it; means it only shifts from the `expired_stop_callback` to the `called_stop_callback` case and is a "if the tree falls in the woods and nobody listens" situation.